# package full ssl cert, w private key and intermediate certs into a single pfx file?

Tags: openssl

I have this kit of files:

- 1.crt: My certificate
- 2.key: private key
- 3.crt: intermediate cert auth (from godaddy)
- 4.crt: root cert or intermediate cert (from godaddy) n.crt: some others like this from godaddy

How do I package all of these into a single pfx for a web server app?

(this needs to be portable , in one file, for deploy purposes)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out 5.P12 -name mycertificate -inkey 2.key -in 1.crt -CAfile 3.crt -caname issuer -CAfile 4.crt -caname root
```

All of this is laid out in https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#file_creation_options